# Spacing issue in table of contents

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I'm new here, so I hope I'm adhering to any community rules.

I am trying to create a table of contents for some notes I'd like to record on LaTex. Here is my code:

---

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.90in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,scrextend}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{5\p@}}%
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \global\@topnum\z@
  \@afterindentfalse
  \secdef\@subsection\@ssubsection}
\renewcommand\section{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{20\p@}}%
  \@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother


    \begin{document}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
%                         Start here
% --------------------------------------------------------------

\lhead{Physics in Medicine}
\chead{}
\rhead{Revision Notes}

\lfoot{} 
\cfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of 16}
\rfoot{}

% \maketitle
\title{\textbf{\textit{Physics in Medicine -- Revision Notes}}}
\date{}

\begin{titlepage}
\vspace{100 mm}
\maketitle
\doublespacing
\tableofcontents
\end{titlepage}
\vfill 

\newpage 

\singlespacing
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section 1: X-ray imaging}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{What are x-rays?}
\section*{Section 1: X-ray imaging}
\vspace{2mm} 
\newline \noindent \textbf{What are x-rays?}

\vspace{3mm} 

\noindent TEXT

\vspace{10mm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Production of x-rays}

\newline \noindent \textbf{Production of x-rays}
\vspace{8mm}
TEXT

\end{document}
```

But the result is shown on the picture - horrible big spaces between the content lines. Don't know how to fix this so advice is appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Why do you manually add the contentslines? When you specify sections and subsections the table of contents can be created automatically.

Comment: I haven't. I've added the code I am using in the body of the text. I am already use the \tableofcontents on the front page. I'm trying to link with the above commands, but the result is as shown :(

Comment: It would be better to provide a full (but small) example document, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that shows this output. With suuch a document it is easier for the community to reproduce your issue and to suggest solutions.

Comment: You can edit your question with the `edit` button below the question text, and you can format code within the question but inserting 4 spaces before the code lines, or by selecting the code and pressing the code formatting button (that looks like `{}`)

Comment: @Marijn I've tried doing that above. Is this ok?

Comment: definitely better :)

Comment: only now it does not compile, because you have taken out too many packages - please try to make it compilable (but still minimal).

Comment: @Marijn I've put some of the packages in. I tried compiling on overleaf and it worked ok. I think the problem is with the \renewcommand stuff about the table of contents (I just took it from the internet, I don't know what any of it actually means)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the problem is solved now? In any case, one of the reasons for the space being larger is `\doublespacing`, when you remove that the space gets smaller.

Comment: No it's not solved. I've just tried removing that but that takes out the space between the Section 1: X-ray imaging and the sub-section of what is X-ray imaging, but does nothing to the gap between the two x-ray imaging lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85839/discussion-between-marijn-and-physicsmathslove).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra space is caused by the redefinition of `\section` and `\subsection`. This code contains the line `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{20\p@}}` (and `5\p@`), which adds 20pt and 5pt of vertical space to the table of contents on each use of the `\section` and `subsection` commands, respectively.

To remove the extra space, you can remove this part of the redefinition (see MWE below). You can also remove the entire redefinition since it is not necessary, unless you require the additional modifications of the (sub)section title behavior of course.

Some additional space is introduced by `\doublespacing` (from the `setspace` package), this can be removed to make the table of contents more compact.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\makeatletter
%\renewcommand\subsection{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{5\p@}}%
\renewcommand\subsection{%
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \global\@topnum\z@
  \@afterindentfalse
  \secdef\@subsection\@ssubsection}
%\renewcommand\section{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{20\p@}}%
\renewcommand\section{%
  \@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{\textbf{\textit{Physics in Medicine -- Revision Notes}}}
\date{}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\doublespacing
\tableofcontents
\end{titlepage}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section 1: X-ray imaging}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{What are x-rays?}
\section*{Section 1: X-ray imaging}

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Production of x-rays}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]